# How do I uninstall MySQL on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard)?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, mysql, uninstall

I had installed MySQL from the command line when I setup a local web server with custom modules on my Snow Leopard box. I recently discovered MAMP and its just easier to work with it than with the personal web server Apple has and via command like utils.

I uninstall ports completely but still see 'mysqld' in my Activity Monitor. I would like to uninstall this cleanly. Any tips?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you haven't yet rebooted your computer, the process could still be running.  First, reboot.

Then if MySQL is still showing up after a reboot, from the Terminal, issue the following commands one at a time<sup>[1](http://akrabat.com/computing/uninstalling-mysql-on-mac-os-x-leopard/)</sup>:

- `sudo rm /usr/local/mysql`
- `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*`
- `sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM`
- `sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*`
- `rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*`
- `sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*`
- `sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*`

And using your text editor of choice:

- Edit `/etc/hostconfig` and remove the line `MYSQLCOM=-YES-`

If you still cannot install or run a different version of MySQL, you might have to issue one last command in the Terminal<sup>[2](http://egopoly.com/2009/09/01/how-to-uninstall-mysql-5-1-on-snow-leopard/)</sup>:

- `sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.mysql*`

Comment: Just tried this on Lion, worked fine for me there too. Thanks!

Comment: I'm over a year late to the party, but one thing I just found was that I also had to remove /etc/my.conf so it wouldn't conflict with my newly installed one.  Thanks for this answer, though; saved me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to do the following

Run this

```
launchctl list|grep mysql
```

Make note of the name of the mysql process name

```
launchctl unload mysql-process-name-from-other-command.plist
```

This will stop the process without need to uninstall or restarting.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to kill the mysqld proccess in the Activity Monitor.

Then you will need to delete the following:

```
/usr/local/mysql
/usr/local/mysql-5.1.45-osx10.5-x86_64/
/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/
/Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL.prefPane/
/Library/Receipts/mysql-5.1.45-osx10.5-x86_64.pkg/
/Library/Receipts/MySQLStartupItem.pkg/
```

Some of the folders with version numbers in them may be names different then what I have listed.

Also this Stackoverflow question may help: [How do you uninstall MySQL from Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x)

Comment: I am unable to kill the process in Activity Monitor. Keeps restarting.