# Trying to uninstall mysql on mac 10.7

Tags: mysql, uninstall

I have followed the instructions here:
[How do I uninstall MySQL on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard)?](https://superuser.com/questions/129193/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard)

Removed / Changed the correct files for what they said.

But when i try a

```
mysql --version
```

It bring back the fact that it is still installed.

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, for osx10.7 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

How can i verify that i actually have it cleaned out and ready for a clean install?

Comment: How did you install it? You probably installed it with a package manager like Homebrew that uses other directories. What's the output of `which mysql`?

Comment: Installed with the package from mysql site for 10.6 since this was the most recent one that they had for osx. Ouput is: /usr/local/bin/mysql

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/mysql*`?

Comment: A lot of files like 32 of them, like this one:lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  32 Jan  9 17:02 /usr/local/bin/mysql -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.5.29/bin/mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Cellar* in the path to `mysql` means that you installed MySQL using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Run the following command to uninstall:

```
brew uninstall mysql
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I forgot that i had installed it via brew before.